# Replace only at the end of the string

Tags: php, string, replace

`echo $string` can give any text.

How do I remove word `"blank"`, **only if it is the last word** of the `$string`?

So, if we have a sentence like `"Steve Blank is here"` - nothing should not removed, otherwise if the sentence is `"his name is Granblank"`, then `"Blank"` word should be removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can easily do it using a regex. The `\b` ensures it's only removed if it's a separate word.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\bblank$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: this code will replace "blank" everywhere, should replace just if it is the last occurance in the string.

Comment: Wrong. That's what the `$` is for.

Comment: @Steve did you try this code? It works on the use case you suggest. the $ indicates a match only if blank is at the end of the string. Although in your specific use case, the regex would be /blank$/, since you don't care about the word boundary.

Answer (score 5):

As a variation on Teez's answer:

```
/**
 * A slightly more readable, non-regex solution.
 */
function remove_if_trailing($haystack, $needle)
{
    // The length of the needle as a negative number is where it would appear in the haystack
    $needle_position = strlen($needle) * -1;  

    // If the last N letters match $needle
    if (substr($haystack, $needle_position) == $needle) {
         // Then remove the last N letters from the string
         $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, $needle_position);
    }

    return $haystack;
}

echo remove_if_trailing("Steve Blank is here", 'blank');   // OUTPUTS: Steve blank is here
echo remove_if_trailing("his name is Granblank", 'blank');  // OUTPUTS: his name is Gran
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
$str = trim($str);
$strlength = strlen($str);

if (strcasecmp(substr($str, ($strlength-5), $strlength), 'blank') == 0)
    echo $str = substr($str, 0, ($strlength-5))
```

Don't use `preg_match` unless it is not required. PHP itself recommends using string functions over regex functions when the match is straightforward. From the [preg_matc](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)h manual page.

Comment: A bit overly complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Not complex then making regular expression and separate function.You can make simpler by doing in steps. We are just using in-built finctions.

Comment: Yes, but consider the maintainability of this solution when compared with the accepted answer...

Answer (score -2):

ThiefMaster is quite correct. A technique that doesn't involve the end of line `$` regex character would be to use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
$trimmed = rtrim($str, "blank");
var_dump($trimmed);
```

^ That's if you want to remove the last characters of the string. If you want to remove the last word:

```
$trimmed = rtrim($str, "\sblank");
var_dump($trimmed);
```

Comment: wouldnot replace "blank" in word like "Granblank" in the end of the string

Comment: Ah well his own definition said "only if it is the last word of the $string" not "only if it is the last characters of the string."  Edited. If that's the case then `rtrim` is even more appealing.

Comment: That's what you asked for, you said if blank is the last WORD of the string, not "if the string ends with 'blank'." However, it would fail if it was "Gran.blank".

Comment: @EboMike: exactly, I've edited to reflect the duality of the question.

Comment: This is *not* how trim/ltrim/rtrim work... The second parameter takes a list of characters to be removed. So `rtrim('Hello bbbbbb', 'blank') = 'Hello '`. Also, it does not accept regex escape sequences.

Comment: @cbuckley: You are not entirely correct. Regex vars aren't supported as part of strings apparently but the second param can take any string, not just single characters. Try the following code on your own computer: https://gist.github.com/1568282

Comment: @editor: As above: *The second parameter takes a list of characters to be removed.* Your code removes any `b`, any `l` and so on, from the end of the string. Have a look at this example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/b4vRUh